# What are good JS libraries for game dev? (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, multimedia

If i decide to write a simple game both text and graphical (2d) what libs may i use? Assuming we are using a HTML5 compatible browser.

The main things i can think of

- Rendering text on screen
- Animating sprites (using images/css)
- Input (capturing the arrow keys and getting relative mouse positions)
- Perhaps some preloading resource or dynamically loading resources and choosing order
- Sound (but i am unsure how important this will be to me at first). Perhaps with mixing and chaining sounds or looping forever until stop.
- Networking (low priority) to connect a user to another or to continuously GET data without multiple request (i know this exist but i dont know how easy it is to setup or use. But this isnt important to me. Its for the question).

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has yet suggested jQuery ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well.... there's [Rocket Engine](http://rocketpack.fi/engine/). I haven't used it, but it appears (on the surface) to do much of what you want.

I'd also recommend [HTML5 Gamer](http://html5gamer.com/), a blog on the issues for building games in HTML5/JS

Answer (score 2):

GameJs does this:

- Sprites, SpriteGroups
- Text rendering
- input handling (key/mouse)
- collision detection
- sound
- resource preloading

http://gamejs.org, Disclaimer: I'm dev of GameJs.

The stuff above works good and I did games with it. The API is similar to http://PyGame.org which some people like a lot.

Networking is planned.

Comment: Hey you might want to look at http://www.effectgames.com/effect/ A company owns it now see http://html5gamer.com/2010/07/effect-games-acquired-by-dextrose-ag-aves-engine/ and aves engine was shown at google. I dont know how impress i am with aves but i am impressed with effect and i suspect effect (and possible aves, maybe one is meant to be free while the other is the enterprise version?) will be THE lib to use.

Comment: a) not open source b) not yet available. And it's a different beast as it works with imgs/css instead of drawing to the canvas.

my lib is on github right now ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with jQuery then [gamequery](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/) is a good one to try. Here's a great demo of what you can do with it: [brainsnackers](http://www.mattpelham.com/brainsnackers/).

Here are some of the features:

- multi layer-sprite animations sprite
- hierarchies (grouping) collision
- detection swappable sound support
- periodic callbacks keyboard state
- polling free and open source license

Answer (score 1):

Check out [cake js](http://code.google.com/p/cakejs/). It's been around a long time and it's really nice to use - especially if you've used actionscript before.

Answer (score 1):

The http://js1k.com contest just ended and the 2D platform game [Legend Of The Bouncing Beholder](http://js1k.com/demo/635) (by [marijnjh](http://twitter.com/marijnjh)) was the winning entry. You might want to look over the source since it would provide a very easy to grasp overview of sidescrollers without needing to read lots of code.

Another good one is the [two-player crazy pong](http://js1k.com/demo/41) which is a lot of fun.

Plus, 1kb games are just awesome.

Answer (score 1):

i would use [RenderEngine](http://www.renderengine.com/) i think it has all you need and solves one of the most important problems that would be collision detection, and it also has sprite support...

[Tutorial](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2010/09/21/making-games-with-javascript-and-renderengine-collision-detection.aspx) <- this is a great tutorial i found

i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Cometd](http://cometd.org) for using ajax push networking (ie. comet)

Answer (score 0):

What about createJS (createjs.com) or melonJS (melonjs.github.io/tutorial)?

CreateJS has great support for those items you mentioned, not so sure about networking though.

MelonJS has native support for reading Tiled tilemap .tmx files.